Chart Js chartjs-plugin-datasource-prometheus changing color for datasets
need some help if someone already used the plugin to use prometheus datasource on chart.js.
I am having problems changing the colors fo the data set.
The best That I was hable to acomplish is to indeed define a color for each but every point as a diferente color:

This is my code:
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            plugins: [ChartDatasourcePrometheusPlugin],
            options: {
                plugins: {
                    'datasource-prometheus': {
                        prometheus: {
                            endpoint: "https://xxx.xx",
                            baseURL: "/api/v1",
                        },
                        query: 'ledger_blockchain_height',
                        timeRange: {
                            type: 'relative',
                            start: -1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                            end: 0, // agora
                        },
                        stacked: true,
                        findInBorderColorMap: function () {
                            return ['rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)'];
                        },
                        findInBackgroundColorMap: function () {
                            return ['rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2)'];
                        },
                        findInLabelMap: function (seriesMetric) {
                            return seriesMetric.labels.job;
                        },
                        fill: true,
                    },
                },
            },
        });

Not sure if I am doing this right, maybe I didn't understand the documentation.
Thank you in advance.

Hello, maybe dependencies are not compatibles. Is it possible to share the full code to check that ?

I think the problem is you are returning a string array instead of a single string.
You can declare a color array this way:
let colors = ['rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)', 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)', 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)'];

Then in your plugin configuration you should tell which color you want on that serie.
findInBorderColorMap: function (serie) {
     return colors.shift();
}

